# Customize ListView using BaseAdabter

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter

I'm developing a customized list view with images and text views in my Android app, however, I followed the tutorial in this link exactly:
http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/#Project_Folder_Structure
. I faced a problem in my ListActivity class when referring to images I placed in the drawable  file, here is my code:
    package com.Android.mysmartrecipeassistant;

```
import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class BookListActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
{
public static final String[] recTitles = new String[] { "Cheese Salad",
    "Burger and Fries", "Chicken", "Sandwiches", "Potato Sauce" };
public static final Integer[] recImgs = new Integer[] {R.drawable.recipe, R.drawable.salad};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

My problem lies in the following line:

```
public static final Integer[] recImgs = new Integer[] {R.drawable.recipe, R.drawable.salad};
```

Though I placed the images in the drawable, my code doesn't see those images and indicates error (the image cannot be resolved or is not a field)

Anyway, I didn't complete the code for this class yet. would you please help me resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest extending from baseAdapter and putting all of the needed logic there , via the getView method.

also , please watch the lecture of "[the world of listView](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html)" for more info of how to use listViews.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing android.R;      import {your.package}.R;